# Is Javascript bind is call by value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning `bind`, `call` and `apply` functions. I am using bind to set callback for the api calls. Here are my functions:

```
function errorCallback(list, error) {
      $log.error('Somehting went wrong while loading json.');
      $log.log(list, error);
    }

    function successCallback(list, response) {
      $log.info('JSON loaded successfully.');
      //$log.log(list, response);
      //this works 
      //$scope.list = list.concat(response.data);
      //this doesn't
      list = list.concat(response.data);
      $log.log($scope.list, list);
    }
```

This is how I am binding them:

```
var successCb = successCallback.bind(null, $scope.list),
      errorCb = errorCallback.bind(null, $scope.list);
```

When I use them as callback:

```
$scope.loadJson = function() {
      $http.get('data.json').then(successCb, errorCb);
    };
```

They are getting invoked properly. But the concern is that when I update  `list` , it does not update the actual parameter which is passed. I want to know that when we bind the parameters for bind, are they bound using value or reference? Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mHZRRn9CEt7UcGsyJcu4?p=preview).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything in JavaScript is passed by value. Some of these values can be references to mutable things (objects - also called reference values), but that's it. When you reassign to `list`, nothing is changing but the `list` variable in your local scope. You actually would need to mutate your array, which `concat` doesn't do - use `push` instead.

If you want to mutate the `$scope`, you will need to pass it itself and explicitly assign its `.list` property.

Comment: **Everything in JavaScript is passed by value** ??.  I think objects are passed by reference

Comment: @murli2308: That's why I stated it so explicitly - because so many don't believe it. Objects are reference values that are still passed by value. The parameter variable does contain a reference (value) to the object, it's not a reference to the "passed variable". Assigning to the variable `list` only changes that variable, no matter whether it contained an object (array) or not.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Bergi makes sense. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`Function.prototype.bind` does the same thing as call or apply, but does not call the function right away instead it returns a new function with your parameters bound to this and when the function is called from a new scope or context, it will remain same.

Binding also allows you to prevent your constructors from being "hacked" by `apply` or `call` since it will always use the binded parameters for this no matter what someone sends to attempt to override this via `call` or `apply`.

If you have noted, the last one does not change from `guest` to `rajini` even though we try to `override` it via `call`.

```
function Profile(u) {
    this.user = u;
    this.getUser = function () {
        return this.user;
    };
}

var x = new Profile('guest');

alert(x.getUser.apply({
    user: 'Vinoth'
})); // Vinoth
alert(x.getUser.call({
    user: 'Google'
})); // Google
alert(x.getUser.bind(x).call({
    user: 'Rajini'
})); // guest
```

A fiddle to play around. 
https://jsfiddle.net/5qxpn4v0/